# How to get the other details when I click next button?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, spring-mvc

```
//This is my controller
@RequestMapping("/getList")
     public ModelAndView getList(@RequestParam(value="page",required=false) Integer page,Model model,@RequestParam(value="page_size",required=false) Integer page_size){
         page=0;
         page_size=4;
         List<Employee> empList = empService.getEmpList1(page,page_size);   
          Employee emp=new Employee();

          model.addAttribute("employee", emp);
          return new ModelAndView("empList", "empList", empList);  
     }
//This is my Sql Query........
select * from EmpDetails LIMIT +page+","+page_size;
//This is my jsp.......for next button.....
 <a href="/getList?page=${page}">Next:</a>
```

By using this code I am getting the records(0-4) of employee in one page.
My question is when I click on next button the records(4-8) of employees must be displayed in other page. Can you please tell me how to write the code?

Comment: Why are you re initializing page and page_size?

Comment: And you should pass page_size along with page in your `url` (href)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
@RequestMapping("/getList")
public String getList(@RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Integer page, Model model,
        @RequestParam(value = "page_size", required = false) Integer page_size) {
    if (page == null) {
        page = 0;
    }
    if (page_size == null) {
        page_size = 4;
    }
    List<Employee> empList = empService.getEmpList1(page, page_size);
    Employee emp = new Employee();

    model.addAttribute("employee", emp);
    model.addAttribute("empList", empList);
    model.addAttribute("page", page);
    model.addAttribute("page_size", page_size);
    return "empList";
}

//This for next button in jsp..... Try and let me know if this link work?
 <a href="getList?page=${page+1}&page_size=${page_size}">Next:</a>

//This is my Sql Query........
recordStart = page * page_size;
select * from EmpDetails LIMIT +recordStart+","+page_size;
```

Comment: If i do this i will get page=1 and page_size=4.But i wat page=8 and page_size=4 i.e,in one page 4 records(in one page from 1-4,in next page 8-11)records.So my page value must be increamented by 4.

Comment: Page signifies page number and not the number of records, so you should pass page number as 1 and at the time of fetching values from database you should prepare value for limit from page number. Did you get my point?

Comment: What problem are you facing ?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/getList?page=1&page_size=4.This iam getting in the url and it is showing requested resource is not available....

Comment: remove `/` from href.

Comment: i am getting into next page when i am clicking on next button i am getting empty page records are not comming....

Comment: Then you should debug your code and find out why it is not fetching or showing next records.

Comment: Naman i have only 8 records so i need show that 8 records in 2 pages(4 in one page) but when i click next it is getting page=3(how can i stop that count).

Comment: For that you need to fire a count query to find out how many records are there in database and then accordingly avoid `next` link in jsp page if you are on last page. And if still someone tried to fetch next page by manually entering values in url then you can check if requested page exist by comparing it with count.

Comment: At present i am writing this query no........select * from EmpDetails LIMIT +page+","+page_size;I need to remove this a?

Comment: You can refer my last comment.

Comment: i am getting duplicate values when clicking on next button like in 1st page(1,2,3,4) in 2nd page(2,3,4,5) in 3rd page(3,4,5,6) and it is getting decreamented Y?

Comment: if i want to perform previous action by pressing previous button can i use same method

Comment: Yes, you just need to pass page number accordingly.

Comment: <a href="getList?page=${page-1}&page_size=${page_size}">Previous:</a>     how can i set (page) value now for this.

Comment: You just need to change href, which you have done right. No change in above java code. Just make sure page value does not go in negative.

Comment: my page value at present is 0 So it obviously goes negative how can i set page value in java code?

Comment: You should handle that in your jsp file using [`<c:if>`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_if_tag.htm)

Comment: Refer the link of `<c:if>`. For any new problem you should ask another question.

Comment: <c:if test="{page!=1}"> can i write like this

Comment: `<c:if test="{page>0}">` would be ideal.

Comment: when the record end the next button should not be performed so i have written like this.......is this correct

Comment: totaCount=12;if(recordStart<=totalCount)

Comment: Change condition to `<` instead of `<=`. **Note:** You should include `<c:if>` condition for this also same as what you have done for previous button in jsp.

Comment: If i want to take total count dynamically  from db then i have wriitten this query(select count(*) from EmpDetails) how to use it to write the condition

Comment: how can use this query in controller to write the condition

Comment: Make another method which will fire your count query and return the count value. And use that method in your controller to fetch count data.

Comment: If this answers your question then kindly [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) this as answer.

Comment: @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public List<Employee> count() {  
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
  List count = new ArrayList();     
    String sql ="select count(*) from EmpDetails";    
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);  
    count = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new EmployeeRowMapper());
    return count;  
   }   ................I have written this in my sql and i used it in controller as.....List<Employee> count=empService.count();
   if(count<recordStart)but it showing error.......is tis code correct.

Comment: If you have new problems you should ask another question!

Comment: //i have written this query......... @Override public int count(){ String sql=EmployeeSqlDao.count_EmpDetails; JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource); int count=jdbcTemplate.queryForInt(sql); return count; } ............i have used in jsp as...................<c:if test="${page<count}" > <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getList?page=${page+1}&page_size=${page‌​_size}">Next</a> </c:if> my count is (20) and my page is getting increamented by 1 so that i getting (empty) records till reach 20.How can solve this please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You should not assign strict values to `page` and `page_size` variables in your method. Instead of this you should get values from parameters passed to method.

```
@RequestMapping("/getList")
public ModelAndView getList(@RequestParam(value="page",required=false) Integer page,Model model,@RequestParam(value="page_size",required=false) Integer page_size){
    List<Employee> empList = empService.getEmpList1(page,page_size);   
    Employee emp=new Employee();

    model.addAttribute("employee", emp);
    return new ModelAndView("empList", "empList", empList);  
}
```

Of course if your `page` and `page_size` is optional then you have to check if values are passed. If not then you have to assign some default values.

Comment: i dont know hw to do it will u plz tell me

Comment: if suppose my default values are 0 and 4 need to increament page like(page+page_size)i.e 8,4.how can i do it when i press next button every time.

Comment: So you have to do this in your logic. You cannot implement this in your controller. Simply on button you have to implements some logic which will be responsible for incrementing `page` variable.

Comment: So how we can pass the increamented value of page to query?

Comment: I told you. You have to pass them with the URL as parameters and then you can pass them to the query,

Comment: //i have written this query......... @Override
    public int count(){
    String sql=EmployeeSqlDao.count_EmpDetails;
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);  
    int count=jdbcTemplate.queryForInt(sql);
    return count;
   }  ............i have used in jsp as...................<c:if test="${page<count}" >
 <a  href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getList?page=${page+1}&page_size=${page_size}">Next</a>
</c:if> my count is (20) and my page is getting increamented by 1 so that i getting (empty) records till reach 20.How can solve this please tell me.